# Swift 3 - having a user send a message to other users in a certain radius

Tags: swift, location

I am learning swift at the moment and was wondering whether it was possible to have a user send a message to all other users in a certain radius. Where would i start?

Anything is appreciated.

Comment: Asking for a tutorial or saying "I don't know where to start" is off the topic here.

Comment: What is certain radius? Is it writing a circle in floor ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need more than swift.
The most simple solution (not the best for performance reason) is to create your REST server o PHP server. Your app will be upload the position of the user to the server and send to the server the message.
The server will send the message to all the user in a certain radius (or it can save the message in a database or buffer and the app will ask sometimes if there are new messages for the current user).
You can also you Firebase like server or something similar.